# need to translate specific t-sql case in pl/sql

Tags: t-sql, plsql, if-statement, case, translate

Can anyone tell me how to translate the following T-SQL statement:

```
SELECT fileld1 = CASE 
                   WHEN T.option1 THEN -1 
                   ELSE
                     CASE WHEN T.option2 THEN 0
                     ELSE 1
                   END
                 END
  FROM Table1 AS T
```

The point is I need to validate two different options from the table for a single field in the select statement..

I have tried to do somthing with an IF statement in pl/sql, but it just doesnt work for me:

```
SELECT IF T.option1 THEN -1 
       ELSE IF T.option2 THEN 0  
       ELSE 1 
       END 
  FROM Table1 AS T
```

I am not actually sure how to write IF statement inside the SELECT statement..
And also, I need to do it INSIDE the select statement because I am constructing a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN T.option1 = ? THEN -1 
         WHEN T.option2 = ? THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END AS field1
  FROM Table1 AS T
```

I can't get your original TSQL to work - I get:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.

...because there's no value evaluation.  If you're checking if the columns are null, you'll need to use:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN T.option1 IS NULL THEN -1 
         WHEN T.option2 IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END AS field1
  FROM Table1 AS T
```

...or if you need when they are not null:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN T.option1 IS NOT NULL THEN -1 
         WHEN T.option2 IS NOT NULL THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END AS field1
  FROM Table1 AS T
```

CASE expressions shortcircuit - if the first WHEN matches, it returns the value & exits handling for that row - so the options afterwards aren't considered.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, PL/SQL also supports the `case`. You just would have to move the column alias from "`field1=`" before the expression to "`AS filed1`" after the expression.